# Does wireless n offer better range than g with obstructions?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have a wireless g router and a wireless USB dongle. I have just recently moved my pc into another room thus putting a brick wall between me and the router. I am now exxoerience drop outs and poor speeds. The router is fine on wireless devices within the room. Which makes me believe it's a range and obstruction issue.

I'm looking at some wireless n routers as they say they have better range and speed than g. My router currently has 1 antenna and the one I'm looking at appears to have 1 antenna.

Will the n router provide better connectivity and speed than my g router? Are there certain things to look for? I'm looking at a d-link router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an answer to your question, but still a possible solution to your problem: [Use an aluminum can as a WiFi extender](http://lifehacker.com/5839243/use-an-aluminum-can-as-a-wi+fi-extender).  Only takes a few minutes to try it out and see if it solves your problem, before buying a new router.

Comment: I might try that. Would it also be worth considering replacing the antenna with something else. I've been looking at some at maplins and wonder if there are certain things i should look for.

Comment: You could look for an external WiFi antenna.  One with a long cable would be best for this.  That would allow you to place the antenna in a better location to either get around the obstruction or at least change the angle of broadcast.  They also make directional antennas, which would do _correctly_ what the tin can is attempting.  Either way it would require that your current router has a removable antenna.

Answer (score 1):

Right now, you want to look for a router with `MIMO` support - these generally have **3** antennas, which they use in a synchronized fashion to significantly increase range (Note, I'm not sure if both the client an AP have to have MIMO, or if just one must have it). While wireless N does provide a bit better range over G or B, It's my understanding that in the 2.4GHz range its focus is increased throughput at the same range, rather than extended range.

You might look into routers which support the 5GHz A and N bands, presuming your devices can also operate in the 5GHz range.

Comment: I'm not very far away from the router, maybe about 15-20 feet, so I think it's just the obstructions that are causing the issue. I wonder if this will be improved with a wireless n router.